# Fix an export for loop that recently stopped working?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, for-loop

I have created several for loops in my GEE script.  These loops worked fine up until a week ago (about 4 months old).  I receive the following error in my console when the code tries to run the for loop to export the rasters as GeoTIFFs:

For loop starts on Line 219
Array.prototype.indexOf called on null or undefined
https://code.earthengine.google.com/75c7c2b933b631e8a61ab4a47d39fabe

I am very new to coding so I don't know too enough to really understand and implement the information in the GEE guide about Server side vs. Client side looping.

Can someone look at my export code and help me figure out how to write new code to export these rasters (1988 to 2017 time series)?

Comment: This is a bug that should be fixed shortly.

Comment: @NicholasClinton thanks for letting me know.  Is there a link that you can provide me that shows Google acknowledging this bug?